# Java - Do two HashSets change similarly overtime?

Tags: java, hashset

I already looked into different questions but these usually ask about consistency or ordering, while I am interested into ordering of two HashSets containing the same elements at the same time.

I want to create a HashSet of HashSets containing integers. Over time I will put HashSets of size 3 in this bigger HashSet and I will want to see if a newly created HashSet is already contained within the bigger HashSet.

Now my question is will it always find duplicates or can the ordering of two HashSets with the same elements be different?

I am conflicted as they use the same hashcode() function but does that mean they will always be the same?

```
HashSet<HashSet<Integer>> test = new HashSet<>();
HashSet<Integer> one = new HashSet<>();
one.add(1);
one.add(2);
one.add(5);
test.add(one);
HashSet<Integer> two = new HashSet<>();
two.add(5);
two.add(1);
two.add(2);
//Some other stuff that runs over time
System.out.println(test.contains(two));
```

Above code tries to illustrate what I mean, does this always return true? (Keep in mind I might initialise another HashSet with the same elements and try the contains again)

Comment: first add two HashSet object like this `test.add(one)` `test.add(two)` , then check your condition, `test.contains(two)`

Comment: It was a mistake, I of course meant to put one into test. But not two. I now also realise test variables names are confusing when talking about them outside code

Comment: By the way, you can put a mutable thing like a set into a hashset and it will work correctly, as long as you don't modify the thing while it is inside the hashset, because that would change its hashcode.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks that is very useful as I will only use it to look up integers and never change them again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the above always returns true. `Set`s have no order, and when you test whether two `Set`s are equal to each other, you are checking that they have the same elements. Order has no meaning.

To elaborate, `test.contains(two)` will return true, if an only if `test` contains an element having the same `hashCode()` as `two` which is equal to `two` (according to the `equals` method).

Two sets `s1` and `s2` that have the same elements have the same `hashCode()` and `s1.equals(s2)` returns true.

This is required by the contract of `equals` and `hashCode` of the `Set` interface:

> **equals**
>
> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set). This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface.
>
> **hashCode**
>
> Returns the hash code value for this set. The hash code of a set is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of the elements in the set, where the hash code of a null element is defined to be zero. **This ensures that s1.equals(s2) implies that s1.hashCode()==s2.hashCode() for any two sets s1 and s2**, as required by the general contract of Object.hashCode.

As you can see, `one` and `two` don't even have to use the same implementation of the `Set` interface in order for `test.contains(two)` to return true. They just have to contain the same elements.

Comment: So essentially the hascode of a Set is the sum of the hashcode of its elements hence it will always be the same regardless of order? That is pretty cool thanks for the extensive explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The **key** property of sets is about **uniqueness** of keys.

By "default", **insertion order** doesn't matter at all.

A **linked** LinkedHashSet guarantees to you that *when* iterating, you get the elements always in the same order (the one used for inserting them). But even then, when comparing such sets, it is still only about their content, not that *insertion order* part.

In other words: no matter what (default) implementation of the `Set` interface you are using, you should always see consistent behavior. Of course you free to implement your own Set and to **violate** that contract, but well, violating contracts leads to violated contracts, aka bugs.

Answer (score -1):

[You can look for yourself](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractSet.java#AbstractSet.equals%28java.lang.Object%29), this is open source code:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;

    if (!(o instanceof Set))
        return false;
    Collection<?> c = (Collection<?>) o;
    if (c.size() != size())
        return false;
    try {
        return containsAll(c);
    } catch (ClassCastException unused)   {
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
        return false;
    }
}

public int hashCode() {
    int h = 0;
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        E obj = i.next();
        if (obj != null)
            h += obj.hashCode();
    }
    return h;
}
```

You can easily see that the hashcode will be the sum of the hashcode of the elements, so it is not affected by any order and that equals use containsAll(...) so also here the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Don’t rely on the source.  It can and has changed over time.  The only thing guaranteed to be consistent over time is the contract—meaning, the javadoc.

Comment: The question was asking specifically about HashSet not about how a Set works in general. I understood that OP wanted to verify that HashSet was following the contract of Set, so providing the Javadoc of Set wasn't useful and the Javadoc of an implementation is not a contract but the description of what the code does.

Comment: “The Javadoc of an implementation is not a contract but the description of what the code does.” Not true at all.  It merely refines (or leaves unchanged) the contract for inherited methods.